# Can't do my software update "not enough space" but disk only half full

Tags: updates

I went to do a software update and got the message that I need to free 10.5M out of /boot

[image]

I did the Trash Empty and the `sudo apt-get clean` but that didn't help.

I deleted some files in /boot but that didn't help or change the message at all.

[image]

I cleaned up my hard drive and it is now less than 50% full.  That didn't help either.  Is the /boot somewhere else perhaps?

[image]